# Working with floating point NumPy arrays for comparison and related operations

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random, precision

I have an array of random floats and I need to compare it to another one that has the same values in a different order. For that matter I use the sum, product (and other combinations depending on the dimension of the table hence the number of equations needed).

Nevertheless, I encountered a precision issue when I perform the sum (or product) on the array depending on the order of the values.

Here is a simple standalone example to illustrate this issue :

```
import numpy as np

n = 10
m = 4

tag = np.random.rand(n, m)

s1 = np.sum(tag, axis=1)
s2 = np.sum(tag[:, ::-1], axis=1)

# print the number of times s1 is not equal to s2 (should be 0)
print np.nonzero(s1 != s2)[0].shape[0]
```

If you execute this code it sometimes tells you that `s1` and `s2` are not equal and the differents is of magnitude of the computer precision.

The problem is I need to use those in functions like `np.in1d` where I can't really give a tolerance...

Is there a way to avoid this issue?

Comment: You can never expect floating point operations to be exact. You should change your algorithm to accommodate some errors. Otherwise there are some fancier sums in the `statistics` module, but that's not really the point now. Especially with numpy, where vectorization should be a basic tool, you can never rely on the order of arithmetic operations.

Comment: How/where are you using `np.in1d`? For the listed code, you can use `np.isclose(s1,s2)`.

Comment: @Divakar I don't use it in the exemple but in my actual algorithm I would use ``np.in1d(s1, s2)`` and other equivalent arrays obtained through other operations like product, etc...

Comment: @Andras Deak I think I need to rethink the choice of my tag... Random floats is probably not a good idea as you point out but it was a convenient one since I am doing this on a very large array and I perform operations like ``tag**3`` which I was afraid would lead to overflows if using integers... I'm opened to suggestions (my tag array must have non repeated values)...

Comment: No, no, the solution is usually not to restrict your data from floats:) My point was the same as that of Divakar: don't use exact tests, use closeness tests. But you seem to be already aware of this, which is why I only suggested to restructure your algorithm to avoid exact tests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the listed code, you can use [`np.isclose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) and with it tolerance values could be specified too.

Using the provided sample, let's see how it could be used -

```
In [201]: n = 10
     ...: m = 4
     ...: 
     ...: tag = np.random.rand(n, m)
     ...: 
     ...: s1 = np.sum(tag, axis=1)
     ...: s2 = np.sum(tag[:, ::-1], axis=1)
     ...: 

In [202]: np.nonzero(s1 != s2)[0].shape[0]
Out[202]: 4

In [203]: (~np.isclose(s1,s2)).sum() # So, all matches!
Out[203]: 0
```

To make use of tolerance values in other scenarios, we need to work on a case-by-case basis. So, let's say for an implementation that involve elementwise comparison like in `np.in1d`, we can bring in [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to do those elementwise equality checks for all elems in first input against all elems in the second one. Then, we use `np.abs` to get the "closeness factor" and finally compare against the input tolerance to decide the matches. As needed to simulate `np.in1d`, we do ANY operation along one of the axis. Thus, `np.in1d` with tolerance using `broadcasting` could be implemented like so -

```
def in1d_with_tolerance(A,B,tol=1e-05):
    return (np.abs(A[:,None] - B) < tol).any(1)
```

As suggested in the comments by OP, we can also round floating-pt numbers after scaling them up and this should be memory efficient, as being needed for working with large arrays. So, a modified version would be like so -

```
def in1d_with_tolerance_v2(A,B,tol=1e-05):
    S = round(1/tol)
    return np.in1d(np.around(A*S).astype(int),np.around(B*S).astype(int))
```

Sample run -

```
In [372]: A = np.random.rand(5)
     ...: B = np.random.rand(7)
     ...: B[3] = A[1] + 0.0000008
     ...: B[6] = A[4] - 0.0000007
     ...: 

In [373]: np.in1d(A,B) # Not the result we want!
Out[373]: array([False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)

In [374]: in1d_with_tolerance(A,B)
Out[374]: array([False,  True, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)

In [375]: in1d_with_tolerance_v2(A,B)
Out[375]: array([False,  True, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Finally, on how to make it work for other implementations and use cases - It would depend on the implementation itself. But for most cases, `np.isclose` and `broadcasting` should help.

Comment: This implementation of in1d with tolerance uses a lot more memory (for big arrays)... so I did instead a ``np.around`` of the arrays I want to compare with a number of decimals close to the floating point precision and it seems to do the job. Thank you.

Comment: @thomleo Good point! Added that into the post, hope that's okay.