# How to stop algorithm if "statement if" is true?

Tags: python, matrix, conditional-statements

I have a if/else statement like this:

```
import numpy as np
rows_b = int(input("Enter the number of rows of matrix B : " ))
column_b = int(input("Enter the number of columns of matrix B : "))

print("Input elements of matrix B1:")
B1= [[float(input()) for i in range(column_b)] for j in range(rows_b)]
   
print("Input elements of matrix B2:")
B2= [[float(input()) for i in range(column_b)] for j in range(rows_b)]

b1 = np.array(B1)
b2 = np.array(B2)

result = np.all(b1 == b2[0])
if result:
    print('matrix B1 = B2')
    #if matrix B1 = B2, go to the next algorithm

else:
    print('matrix B1 and B2 are not equivalent') 
    #if B1 and B2 are not equivalent, stop here.

B = np.array(B1)
print("Matrix B is: ") 
for x in B:
    print(x)
```

I want if B1 = B2 then continue to the next step (B = np.array (B1)) but (else) if B1 and B2 are not equal then stop algorithm (not continue to B = np.array (B1)), how ?

Comment: Either keep rest of the code from `B = np.array(B1)` inside the `if` condition, or use `exit()`in `else` part.

Comment: Obligatory warning: you can't [compare floating point](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/6486738) values! You need to compare it with an epsilon, or with [`isclose` in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39757559/6486738).

Comment: @ThePyGuy No, `exit` is not the way to go. To cite the [documentation of `exit` and `quit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#exit): "They are useful for the interactive interpreter shell and should not be used in programs."

Comment: @Matthias, That's is also `True`. `exit` is not a recommended way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it inside `if`

```
if B1 == B2:
  B = np.array(B1)
  print("Matrix B is: ") 
  for x in B:
    print(x)

else:
    print('matrix B1 and B2 are not equivalent') 
    #if B1 and B2 are not equivalent, stop here.
```

Comment: I'd suggest adding the same warning here. `B1 == B2` will compare all elements, and floating-point values [can't accurately be compared with equality](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/6486738).

Comment: so what should i do to compare with float value?

Comment: how to use np.isclose() in if/else statment?

Comment: @MiraWadu If you just want to check if all elements in one array is equal to all the elements in the other array, you could use `if np.allclose(B1, B2)`. Read up on it [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html).