# How to compare two columns values in two dataframes in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare

I have two dataframes and I have created a "Check" column in second dataframe to check if values in the Total Claims columns are equal. Here are my two dataframes:

**Dataframe 1**

[image]

**Dataframe 2**

[image]

The code that I used to create the "Check" column comparing Total Claims between the two dataframes was:

```
reported_claims['Check'] =  np.where(reported_claims['Total Claims'].reset_index(drop=True) == df['Total Claims'].reset_index(drop=True) , 'TRUE', 'FALSE')
```

I noticed that the 7th values in two dataframes are both 31.32 but the check columns says False. I was just wondering why is it saying False and how would I fix this problem? Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue arises by comparing two floating point numbers. The general rule for most programming languages (including python) is that you can never check if two floats are **exactly equal**. You have to instead check if the two values are close.
You can do so using the [np.isclose()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html). Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39758154/8655058) for a reference on how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Use merge command to join two dataframe and add check column to compare two columns

```
df = pd.merge(left=Dataframe1, right=Dataframe2, left_on='month', right_on='month')
```